# ProgressBar Control no effect if its style is ProgressBarStyle.Marquee

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, progress-bar

I am trying to test progress bar with marquee style but with no succeed

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();

        this.progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        this.progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 100;
        //this.progressBar1.Value = 0;
    }
```

Update:
At [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.marqueeanimationspeed.aspx)

The Marquee style is only supported in Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows Server 2003 Platform could this be the problem?

**Update2:**
It seems the problem with a theme I installed on my machine not on the xp version... I removed the theme and the problem is just gone!

Comment: Your interpretation is false, of course. The Marquee style is **fully supported** on 32-bit versions of Windows XP. I've used it myself many times, and the operating system uses it internally several places as well. But you actually have to *start* the marquee animation; you won't see anything with the code that you have.

Comment: @Cody Gray: If you are sure please provide some code that actually works in windows XP 32 professional, however this is not my interpretation; it is from the MSDN link:  "Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows Server 2003 Platform Note: The Marquee style is supported only on these platforms."

Comment: There's no possible way that could be true. Windows XP Home and Professional are the **exact same operating system**. As are Windows XP x64 and Windows Server 2003. And *all* of them include the same version of `comctl32.dll`, which is what provides the implementation for the progress bar control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that several of the answers are reading the documentation is completely incorrect. In fact, the marquee style is **fully supported** on *all* versions of Windows XP, including 32-bit Home & Professional, as well as the x64 Edition (which really has more in common with Windows Server 2003 than XP). The reason that you know without a doubt that all of these operating systems support the control is because they all include the identical version of `comctrl32.dll`, which is what provides the implementation for the progress bar control.

I myself have used this style many times in applications, including those that run on Windows XP, and have never had a problem. In fact, as I mentioned in a comment, these versions of the operating system use this style of progress bar internally in several of the shell dialogs.

I've been challenged to provide code that demonstrates this apparently evasive phenomenon... I'm not really sure how to do that, as the code shown in the question works just fine for me. So I guess I'll just reprint that here, along with some screenshots:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        this.progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 100;
    }
}
```

Running under Windows XP with the Luna theme enabled:

[image: Marquee progress bar control running under Windows XP with the Luna Homestyle theme]

And running under Windows XP with the Classic theme enabled:

[image: Marquee progress bar control running under Windows XP with the Classic theme]

This is all from a clean virtual machine with Windows XP Professional SP3 32-bit loaded. For proof:

[image: "System Properties" from the demo machine, indicating that it is, in fact, Windows XP Professional SP3 32-bit]

**Edit:** It appears that if you have a custom theme installed, the marquee style may not show up correctly. Check your settings in the Display control panel. The built-in Luna (Windows XP) and Classic themes work correctly, as does the unofficial "Watercolor" theme. Theme designers are responsible for designing these elements and incorporating them into their themes. If you notice that your theme does not support this style, please contact the source for an update.

Comment: You are right... After you mentioned the Luma theme and windows xp classical theme; I remove a theme that I were installed on my machine and run the xp theme and the problem just disappears... So the problem was in the theme not in the xp version; thanks for your effort and the screen shots..

Comment: Please state at your answer that the problem may be in a theme installed on the tested machine so I can flag your answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

You should call `EnableVisualStyle` before you create form.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.APPLICATION.ENABLEVISUALSTYLES%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true):

> To have an effect,
>   EnableVisualStyles() must be called
>   before creating any controls in the
>   application; typically,
>   EnableVisualStyles() is the first line
>   in the Main function

Comment: Thanks.. however I found the answer check my question update.

Comment: This isn't strictly necessary. The progress bar style is fully supported *without* visual styles (themes) enabled, as the screenshot of the control running under the "Classic" theme in my answer indicates.

Comment: @Cody - I made a test application. If I comment `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` line in Main function progress bar doesn't do anything. I have Windows 7. So I figured that Jalal has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the answer is found in this extract from the documentation:

> **Windows XP Home Edition,
>   Windows XP Professional x64
>   Edition, Windows Server 2003
>   Platform Note**: The Marquee style is supported only on these platforms.

I guess you are on a different platform.

Comment: it looks like this is your answer then

Answer (score 0):

Even though the answer was already given, for those who may encounter the problem it is possible that the progress bar has `Maximum` set to 0. In that case there will be no animation even with `Style` and `MarqueeAnimationSpeed` set to correct values.